# How to minify legacy javascript libraries (ES6)

Tags: webpack, gulp, uglifyjs, gulp-uglify, uglifyjs2

I have several legacy JS libraries for a website that I would like to minify (and ideally also concatenate into one bundle). However, since the libraries use ES6 syntax I cannot simply use `uglify-js` on command line and minify since it requires the code to already be transpiled to ES5. I need the library functions to remain accessible via global var for now until I can properly port them to ES6 using import/export directives.

I've looked into two approaches:

1. I've tried to use Gulp to transpile the code first, however the transpiled code now contains `require()` statements in order to import the `js-core` polyfills. And consequently the code cannot run in the browser yet. *Not sure if it is possible to take this further...*
2. Webpack can transpile and minify but it seems Webpack requires use of import/export directives in JS code in order to load and minify them (note one can use [`script-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/#other-utilities) however the files is then simply included and evaluated as a whole but not minified).

The optimal solution is obviously to port the legacy code to use Webpack. But this is too much effort for the time being.

**So, is there any way I can easily minify the files I have without porting the legacy code to use imports/exports?**

Lets assume that I have two libraries `mylib1.js` and `mylib2 js`. They depend on using `jQuery`, `Lodash` and other libraries which are accessed via globals `$`, `_` etc. `mylib2.js` depends on functions from `mylib1.js`. Currently the libraries are loaded in proper sequence and all functions are accessed via single global variable: e.g. MyLib1.doSomething() and MyLib2.doSomething2().

File `MyLib1.js`:

```
// Declare library
var MyLib1 = {};

MyLib1.someGlobalConstant1 = 123;
MyLib1.someGlobalConstant2 = 456;

function concatData(x, y){
  return "Concatenated:" + x + "_" + y;
}

// Declare library function
MyLib1.doSomething = () => {
  let b; 
  let c = { x: 1, y: 2 };

  function joinData(x){
        return { ...c, h: 9 };
  }

  return joinData(d);
}

MyLib1.doSomething2 = (x, y) => {
  return concatData(x, y);
}
```

The resulting minified & prettified file (using Gulp, as explained in 1. above):

```
'use strict';
function _objectSpread(t) {
  for (var e = 1; e < arguments.length; e++) {
    var r = null != arguments[e] ? arguments[e] : {},
      o = Object.keys(r);
    'function' == typeof Object.getOwnPropertySymbols &&
      (o = o.concat(
        Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(r).filter(function(e) {
          return Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(r, e).enumerable;
        })
      )),
      o.forEach(function(e) {
        _defineProperty(t, e, r[e]);
      });
  }
  return t;
}
function _defineProperty(e, t, r) {
  return (
    t in e
      ? Object.defineProperty(e, t, {
          value: r,
          enumerable: !0,
          configurable: !0,
          writable: !0
        })
      : (e[t] = r),
    e
  );
}
require('core-js/modules/web.dom.iterable'),
  require('core-js/modules/es6.array.iterator'),
  require('core-js/modules/es6.object.keys');
var MyLib1 = {};
function concatData(e, t) {
  return 'Concatenated:' + e + '_' + t;
}
(MyLib1.someGlobalConstant1 = 123),
  (MyLib1.someGlobalConstant2 = 456),
  (MyLib1.someGlobalConstant3 = 789),
  (MyLib1.doSomething = function() {
    return d, _objectSpread({}, { x: 1, y: 2 }, { h: 9 });
  }),
  (MyLib1.doSomething2 = function(e, t) {
    return concatData(e, t);
  });
```

Example `gulpfile.js`:

```
const { src, dest } = require('gulp');
const babel = require('gulp-babel');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
const prettier = require('gulp-prettier');

exports.default = function() {

  return src('src/js/*.js')
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(dest('dist-transpiled'))
    .pipe(uglify({warnings: true}))
    .pipe(prettier({ singleQuote: true }))    
    .pipe(dest('dist/js'));
}
```

Comment: Can you use https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-es ?  It is made for es6+.

Comment: Thanks @Mark! Yeah that works, except I have to use terser.js (https://www.npmjs.com/package/terser) instead which is a fork of uglify-js (which no longer is maintained).